# Function pointer in class A to member function from class B

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I'm searching a solution for this for a few days now. Didn't find any question related enough to answer regrettably so here is my question.
Consider the next code:

```
// dummy class A
class A {
public:
    void aFunction() { // <- this is the function I want to point at
        cout << "aFunction() is called\n";
    }
};

class B {
public:
    template <class Class> // get a function pointer
    void setFunction( void (Class::*func)() ) {
        p_func = func;
    }
    void (*p_func)(); // the function pointer
}

int main() {
    B obj;
    objb.setFunction(&A::aFunction);
    return 0;
}
```

I have a compilation error in `setFunction()` on `p_func = func;`:

> cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall A::* )(void)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void)'

And I don't seem to be able to get rid of it in any way. I know it has something to do with those invisible `this` pointers (`__thiscall` and `__cdecl`), but I don't know how to handle these. I tried making the member variable `p_func` a class template too (`void (Class::*p_func)()`) so it would have the same structure, but it that seems to be illegal to have 2 class templates in one class (why?), thus isn't the correct solution. This time the compiler complains about:

> multiple template parameter lists are not allowed

This method (without the template) works perfectly on global functions (which is the workaround I currently use) and I saw the use of it in a library (sfgui), so it should be perfectly possible.

To have some context over why I'd want this: I'm trying to create a button. This button should be able to call whatever function I'd like. For now, I'd like it to call the `start()` function of an animation class I'm making.

p.s.: I know this example is useless since I can't run `p_func`: the function isn't static. I still need to add an object pointer (`setFunction( void (Class::*func)(), Class* )`), but that does not seem to be a problem. And I know about `typedef` to make a function pointer more readable, but not with a class template.

---

### EDIT

After some more research I think the answer I need not the answer to this question, but rather another one. For once, I noticed that multiple `template <class Class>` is in fact allowed. However, it is not allowed on member variables since the compiler can't possibly know which `class` he'll need to use which probably is the reason for the error

> multiple template parameter lists are not allowed

which is an odd description. Thanks anyway for the help, you did gave me a better insight.

Comment: A pointer to a member function is an entirely separate type from a pointer to a non-member function -- you can't mix the two (and to use a pointer to a member function, you need something like  `object.*pmf()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the complete answer myself while searching for a way to save *objects of an unknown type without using templates or void pointers which has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570676/c-member-variable-of-any-type-in-non-template-class). The solution is a bit dodgy, because you'll have to create a dummy parent which allows for certain conversions.

The idea is that you create a Parent and every object that is allowed to be pointed to must inherit from it. This way you can create a pointer as `Parent *obj` which can hold multiple types of objects, but of course only classes that inherit from `Parent`.

The same applies for function pointers. If you define your pointer as `void (Parent::*func)()` as member variable. You can ask the user a template function pointer `template <class Class> setFunction( void (Class::*f)() )`, which can hold any pointer to any class. Now you need to cast the function pointer to the desired class, `Parent`: `static_cast<void(Parent::*)()>(f)`. Mind that this only works when Class inherits from Parent. Otherwise you'll get a compilation error.

### Minimal Working Example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// dummy class Parent
class Parent {};

// class A
class A : public Parent { // Mind the inheritance!
public:
    A(int n) : num(n) {}

    void print() {  // <- function we want to point to
        cout << "Number: " << num << endl;
    }

    int num;
}

// class B, will hold the 2 pointers
class B {
public:
    B() {}

    template <class Class>  // will save the function and object pointer
    void setFunction( void (Class::*func)(), Class *obj) {
        function = static_cast<void(Parent::*)()>(func);
        object = obj;
    }

    void execFunction() {  // executes the function on the object
        (object->*function)();
    }

    void (Parent::*function)(); // the function pointer
    Parent *object;             // the object pointer
}

int main() {
    A a(5);
    B b;

    b.setFunction(&A::print, &a);
    b.execFunction();

    return 0;
}
```

---

I don't really like this solution. A better solution would be that class `B` could have a function where it returns a bool when the function needs to be executed. This way you could simply place an `if` statement in the `main`-function that executes the desired function.

```
A a(5);
B b;
while (;;) {
    if (b.aTest())
        a.print();
}
```

Where `B::aTest()` is declared as

```
bool B::aTest();
```

Hope this helps anyone that comes across the same problem. So it is perfectly possible but pretty dodgy in my opinion, and I don't encourage people using the first method.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot convert a pointer-to-member `Class::*func` to a normal function pointer.  They are of different types.

You should turn this:

```
void (*p_func)(); // the function pointer
```

into this:

```
void (class::*p_func)(); // the function pointer
```

You could also use a `std::function<void()>` and use `boost::bind` to bind it.

```
std::function<void()> fun = boost::bind(class::member_fun, args);
```

**EDIT**

What about making your B class a template so you can do this:

```
#include<iostream>

class A {
public:
    void aFunction() { // <- this is the function I want to point at
        std::cout << "aFunction() is called\n";
    }
};

template<class T>
class B {
public:
    void setFunction( void (T::*func)() ) {
        p_func = func;
    }
    void (T::*p_func)(); // the function pointer
    void callfunc()
    {
       (t.*p_func)(); //call pointer to member
    }
   private:
   T t; 
};

int main() {
    B<A> obj;
    obj.setFunction(&A::aFunction);
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4s94dz%2417)

Comment: I tried your first solution (as I've stated in my question). That would mean I'd need another `template <class Class>` ahead of the member variable declaration which is illegal according to the compiler. I'll try out the `boost::bind`-method.

Comment: well I though of that too, but the button needs to have several function pointers: while hovering, while stop hovering, when clicked and when released. I can't let them all point to the same class. But I'll come back in a minute, for now I'm trying to install the boost libraries first :) Thanks already for the quick answer!

Comment: Ok, I played a bit with the functions you gave me, but these seem to be not a lot different than the usual pointers I use. Since you still need the `template <class Class>` syntax which I can't use more than once per class...